# How to import a csv file into react table correctly?

Tags: reactjs, csv

I have a react code which has a "Upload" button to import a .CSV file and show its data in a react table.

Its data is something like these two rows:

[csv file image][1]

I wrote the following code for uploading the data:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { CsvToHtmlTable } from 'react-csv-to-table';
import ReactFileReader from 'react-file-reader';


const App = () => {

  const [csvData, setCsvData] = useState(''); 

  const handleFiles = files => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload =  (e) => {
      // Use reader.result
      console.log("dd:",reader.result)
      setCsvData(reader.result)
    }
    reader.readAsText(files[0]);
  } 

  return(
   <div>
      <ReactFileReader 
        multipleFiles={false}
        fileTypes={[".csv"]} 
        handleFiles={handleFiles}>
        <button className='btn'>Upload</button>
      </ReactFileReader>
      <CsvToHtmlTable
        data={csvData}
        csvDelimiter=","
        tableClassName="table table-striped table-hover"
      />
  </div>
  )  

}

export default App;
```

Now as the "csvDelimiter" is equal to "," and the data in "P" column has "," in its format, it doesn't show the data correctly in the table as it splits the number in "P" column by "," and we see something like this:

[Result Table][2]

How can I show the data correctly. I also need the values of the cvs file to be cleaned up before being shown in the table. For example, LS value "31,715 Lot" should be converted into integer, namely 31715. "P" column value is "$4,875", which should become currency with real value.

How can I clean them and show them in table correctly?

Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLBbJ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGkGr.png

Comment: Either your input CSV is wrong, or your parser is broken. Comma's can totally appear in csv fields, if they are surrounded by double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to import csv data into react table.

https://github.com/manaspandey45/react-csv-data-table

```
import Papa from 'papaparse';
```

And then fetch the csv

```
  fetchCsv() {
    return fetch('/data/data.csv').then(function (response) {

      let reader = response.body.getReader();
      let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');

      return reader.read().then(function (result) {
        return decoder.decode(result.value);
      });
    });
  }
    async getCsvData() {
    let csvData = await this.fetchCsv();
    let results = Papa.parse(csvData, { header: true })
    this.getData(results)

  }
```

Comment: It's weird that you're importing `Papa` but then you're not using it.

Comment: Missed the papa usage snippet.. Added it